# What exactly belongs in a multimedia category?

Tags: categorization

I have a website with categories like "news", "articles" and also a category called **"Multimedia"** where I would like to put video (embedded from YouTube and Vimeo) and audio (podcasts, SoundCloud etc.).

But now I am a little confused how the users would see that in my Main menu because the description of [Multimedia on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia) is a little confusing, at least for me.

Could I, for example, also include application downloads within "Multimedia"?

What about other stuff that can be embedded like Scribd documents? Could I include that in the Multimedia category?

Do people consider "Multimedia" to be only audio and video, or do they expect other embedded content and download links (applications)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multimedia is frequently used for video and audio information. So it's a kind of data. Sowtfare is not data, it's functionality. I think it would be confusing to find application under Multimedia.

Also software is the separate world. It has updates, platforms versions, help and support. **So give to software separate place and label**.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say, but I have to strongly disagree with "Software is not data". It is! A special kind of data maybe, but data nonetheless.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus – software is binary data, of course. But that kind of data is not percievable by users, they can't watch or read it. So I mean from UX point content is divided on Multimedia (data consumption) and Software (data processing).

Comment: One more question. How would the users get the fact if I use just "Media" instead of "Multimedia"? Would they get that I mean just audio and video and not articles etc.? Because, media could be newspapers, probably digital articles too. What is your opinion? "Media" are shorter in the menu ;)

Comment: @Derfder – I think **"Media" is ok**, it would be clear for users from other menu labels. So, if there "Article" label then "Media" is something separate from articles and so on. It is scenario for first-time visitors. Returning visitors just know/remember this from previous experience from your site.